# intelliJ not freshing file

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a Spring Maven based project, its running fine. I just updated my svn from directly right click > Update. Now I have new files in my folder but in intelliJ IDE its still showing the old files.

How can I refresh my project in intelliJ so it have the latest files from folder.

I am using intelliJ 12 ultimate edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do Synchronize from the project window, but you shouldn't need to.  I would check the old copies are not in a different place to where you expect.  Try using the (><) button in the project windows to see where they come from.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all the files are local and there are no symlinks. If you are using remote file system or symlinks, deleting `bin/fsnotifier` binary can help. In any case it's a bug that [should be reported](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA).